# Wordpress site not rendering properly on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I am a newbie to wordpress development and somehow managed to put together a website - http://www.checkgaadi.com.

However, I am simply not able to get this to work properly on a mobile device.

Have tried several plugins (e.g., WPtouch, WP Mobile detector etc.) which are supposed to help. Here when I tried WPtouch for the first time it went to a "mobile site" and was more or less responsive. There was also a button to switch to desktop site. I clicked this button and now I only see a distorted version of desktop website on mobile, but now I don't find the button to go back to mobile theme. I have tried deleting the plugin and reinstalling, deleting the "wptouch-data" folder etc hoping to clear the cache and several other tricks but nothing seems to bring back that button to switch between desktop and mobile themes.

**Anyone who has some experience with WPtouch (or any other simple plugin you recommend) may perhaps tell me how to get that "switch mobile<->desktop" button back?** For the moment I have disabled WPtouch on the website so you may not see it.

As a second option, it seems to me that only certain parts of the landing page need fixing (e.g., some CSS tinkering with the topmost part) and mostly it should be okay without really getting into the WPtouch stuff. **Could someone please give me guidance with the CSS modifications needed to fix the issue?**

Thanks so much.

Comment: The first issue of not getting the "switch" button can be resolved by clearing browser cookies, however it seems like I certainly need to clean up the CSS mess on my webpage in order to get the website working. It is because the WPtouch seems good for typical blog websites but not heavily customized wordpress themes.

Answer (score 1):

Just click the "core settings" of Wptouch. Then you will see the general settings. There is a "Desktop / Mobile Switching" option under the "Landing page" option. Put a tick into "Show switch link in mobile view" box. I hope it will work for you

Comment: I think you are referring to the WPtouch Pro version of the plugin. There is no such option in the standard version unfortunately...